# Which C# SDK is suitable for development , Quantoz or Elucidsoft?

Tags: c#-sdk

There are 2 C# SDK's available.

https://github.com/QuantozTechnology/csharp-stellar-base and https://github.com/elucidsoft/dotnet-stellar-sdk.

I see active development on elucidsoft SDK. Any recommendation on which SDK to use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/elucidsoft/dotnet-stellar-sdk appears to be more popular, and was called out specifically as a project to contribute to in the latest SBC announcement.

https://www.stellar.org/blog/announcing-the-7th-stellar-build-challenge/

That's the one I'd go with.